# Get anchor tag URL with javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to store the url of a anchor tag in a variable but I keep getting an error.

```
var buttonUrl = document.getElementById('test').href;
```

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'href' of null`

Comment: please provide full html + js

Comment: we just need know the tag of id test element

Comment: `button` tags don't have `href` attribute ! Provide your code that may help.

Comment: `<a id="test" href="www.google.com/" target="_self"><span class="label"><strong>Button</strong></span></a>`

Comment: The immediate cause of your error is surely that no element in your page has `id`="test". Moreover, it is _hyperlinks_ `<a>` which have `href` attribute, not _buttons_.

Comment: Use the javascript debugger, see what the result of `document.getElementById('test')` is.

Comment: I just tested your code quickly and got the same error. I then realised that it was because I was calling document.getElementById before the document had loaded. So I put my javascript inside a function which checks if the document has loaded before trying to reference any elements by their ID (and it works). If you do as follows it should work: window.onload = function(){ var buttonUrl = document.getElementById('test').href; }

Comment: Most likely either you made a typo, or your script is running before the element has loaded (e.g. if it runs immediately and you put the script tag above the element tag).  Hard to tell without seeing the actual code.

Comment: the script was running before the element was loaded. Problem solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your code is running *after* the window loads:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var buttonUrl = document.getElementById("test").href;
    console.log(buttonUrl);
    //This will log the href of the "test" element to the console as a debugger. You can now use buttonUrl as you want.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

sometimes you need to refer to the index of the element like zero. Try this instead

`var buttonUrl = document.getElementById('test')[0].href`

Comment: I think that doesn't apply there, that's to get the plain DOM element when using jQuery.